# How can I restart Windows machine from OS X by command line?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I have MacBook Pro with OS X 10.6.7 and I have a Windows XP machine. I want to restart the Windows machine through the OS X command line. For example in Windows we can restart with this command:

`shutdown -m \\IP -r -t 00`

It will be restarted immediately.

How can I do this with a Mac?

Comment: So you are wanting to know how to SSH via a mac to a windows machine so you can type the command you described?

Answer (score 6):

If you have Samba tools installed, you can do

```
net rpc shutdown -r -I <IP> -U <username>
```

Comment: Where do I get Samba tools?

Comment: Samba tools have been removed from the system in Lion, but you can install them via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/): `brew install samba` Note, though, that it can conflict with Apple's proprietary smbd, and re-enables parameters in smb.conf

Answer (score 4):

You could just use the [Windows RDP tool for Mac](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client) and RDP into your Windows XP machine and run the command,

```
shutdown -r -t 0
```

To restart the system without RDP then you can install an SSH Server (This [forum thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/19864-ssh-windows-7-a.html) could be of interest, but the link below includes the page to OpenSSH binaries for Windows anyway.) onto your Windows Machine and then simply accessing the Windows machine like:

```
ssh User@192.168.0.5
```

Will take you to the Windows command prompt, and I believe you could just run the Shutdown Command through SSH.

Here's a website I found, maybe you can make some sense out of it:
http://www.tonyspencer.com/2005/12/03/restart-windows-remotely-through-vpn/

Comment: I know I can do it with RDP but is there another idea can connect to windows machine via bash?

Comment: Changed my answer, hopefully it will help you further

Answer (score 2):

If your Windows box were running Windows *Server*, then you could RDP into a command-line only session and probably pipe the command `shutdown -r -t 1` into the RDP session.

If your Windows box had an SSH server installed, then you could ssh in and do the same thing. I don't think there is another way--unless your Mac has a robotic arm attachment that could be controlled via the command-line to press the restart button on the XP box.

Comment: But I don't want to RDP can I do it from bash directly? or there is no solutions

Comment: Well, there is something called "Services for Unix", or more recently, "Unix Subsystem" that Windows supports. It's a unix-like environment within Windows--but I think you'd still need an ssh server (or sim.) running to accept remote connections.